# Unable to click on link in flip-wrapper

Tags: css, 3d, transform, css-transforms

I am using transform property which works fine but if i add any link there then it won't work and rotates back quickly on -180 deg if I click the back card.
I tried to remove the "flipped" class on mouse leave but no luck. Any suggestion please?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.flipWrapper {
 -webkit-perspective: 1000;
 -moz-perspective: 1000;
 -ms-perspective: 1000;
 -o-perspective: 1000;
 perspective: 1000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align:center;
}

.flipWrapper .card.flipped {
 -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 transform: rotatey(180deg);
}
.flipWrapper .card {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 transition: 0.5s;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
.flipWrapper .card .face {
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;
 background:#383838;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 2;
}
.flipWrapper .card .front {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.flipWrapper .card .back {
 -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 background:#383838;
 cursor: pointer;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
} 
.flipWrapper .card .back p{
 padding-top:20px;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
} 
.flipWrapper .card .back p:last-child{
 padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipWrapper">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="face front">
            <img src="http://magicpatrick.fr/images/r2.png"alt=""></div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p><small><em>Mariages</em></small></p>
                <p>L’événement le plus magique de la vie d’une personne, le jour de son mariage, est un jour à marquer d’une pierre blanche, et quelle plus belle façon de le célébrer qu’avec un artiste hors du commun. </p><br><a class="" href="google.com">Read more</a>
               
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this

```
$("a.read-more-link").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and you `Read More` link be `<a class="read-more-link" href="google.com">Read more</a>`

**event.stopPropagation();**

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and
>   bubbling phases.

Read more about [event.stopPropataion()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        return false;
    });
  $("a.read-more-link").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

```css
.flipWrapper {
 -webkit-perspective: 1000;
 -moz-perspective: 1000;
 -ms-perspective: 1000;
 -o-perspective: 1000;
 perspective: 1000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align:center;
}

.flipWrapper .card.flipped {
 -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotatey(180deg);
 transform: rotatey(180deg);
}
.flipWrapper .card {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 transition: 0.5s;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
.flipWrapper .card .face {
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;
 background:#383838;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 2;
}
.flipWrapper .card .front {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.flipWrapper .card .back {
 -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 transform: rotatey(-180deg);
 background:#383838;
 cursor: pointer;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
} 
.flipWrapper .card .back p{
 padding-top:20px;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
} 
.flipWrapper .card .back p:last-child{
 padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipWrapper">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="face front">
            <img src="http://magicpatrick.fr/images/r2.png"alt=""></div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p><small><em>Mariages</em></small></p>
                <p>L’événement le plus magique de la vie d’une personne, le jour de son mariage, est un jour à marquer d’une pierre blanche, et quelle plus belle façon de le célébrer qu’avec un artiste hors du commun. </p><br><a class="read-more-link" href="google.com">Read more</a>
               
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Noted, Thank you so much :)